# Mobile apps server side programming (Accessing google calendar usingPHP)

Tags: php, android, authentication, google-calendar-api

I am trying to access google calendar from php program.  I am using a php program as middle person to communicate with my android program and Goolge Calendar.

Google provided API to access calendar. when I try to access calendar it asks for authentication, then Login to google account, then Grant Access permision. My problem is I don't need multiple steps to access calendar. I will send Gmail ID and Password from android program to php by calling Calendar.php(For ex:), then php should receive that and directly login to Google Calcendar.

Comment: Yes . i need to access GCalendar directly while calling that php file.

Comment: People here won't just hand you code. You need to try for yourself, and then come back when you have an actual programming problem. What have you tried?

Comment: ya . i have tried to access calendar from my php program . its working good . k i ll do more with my code n ask u later ..... thanks for d reply.:)

Comment: When you ask later, definitely add in code that you're having problems with and have a very specific question in mind.

Comment: Sorry am newer to stack overflow..so.

Comment: I suggest reading through the FAQ linked in the top right, and also reading through some other questions to see examples of what gets high votes (i.e. good questions) and what doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. Google uses OAuth for all it's 3rd party plugins, so the user has to go to a google page to authenticate, and then your app is given an OAuth key to use.

This is to stop you from maliciously storing the username and password given to your app and mis-using it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try the Canlendar.php demo from ZEND_GDATA which provided by google?
specially function 'outputCalendar'.that's the function to retrieve events from google calendar.
You can preview codes [here](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/demos/Zend/Gdata/Calendar.php)

you should download demos somewhere and check yourself :)

Comment: ya . am trying that only. its working good. but i need to login to calendar at one step.